# Help with a modifier: "Combined"

Tags: modifiers

I am hoping for some help with the following statement from a construction contract:

*The amounts of all subcontracts, provided that such amounts shall include a maximum of 10% mark-up for overhead and profit combined (including management, supervision, insurance, bonding, as-built and warranty costs) for those Subcontractors and their suppliers.*

Does the word "combined" refer to "overhead and profit" or "Subcontractors and their suppliers".

I work in construction, and have a situation where someone is trying to tell me that my company, our sub-contractor, and all of our suppliers are only entitled to share a total markup of 10%.

Comment: That is what lawyers are really good for...

Comment: Without a comma before it, *combined* extends the noun-phrase immediately preceding: *overhead and profit* -- there's no ambiguity. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The word combined refers to overhead and profit. It would have most probably been placed at the end of the statement for referring to the sub-contractors and suppliers.